# Auto hide taskbar when on desktop

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Is it possible to auto hide the taskbar when there is no opened window. I mean when there is a window in taskbar, the taskbar should be visible but when there is no window taskbar should auto hide

Edit: I mean when there is an open window the auto hide feature will get disable and when there is no open window, the auto hide feature get enabled

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the taskbar and select properties.  Make sure the checkbox is checked next to "Auto-Hide the Taskbar" and select "OK".  The taskbar should drop down when you are on the desktop.  To bring the taskbar back up, move your mouse to the bottom of the desktop.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. But, I mean when there is an open window the auto hide feature will get get disable and when there is no open window, the auto hide feature get enabled.